# T-SQL use LAG with unknown number of rows

Tags: sql, function, t-sql

I need to work out the time between an alarm being created and cleared. The alarm can go through a series of stages, with a new row for each state change. The number of rows is therefore not constant. I need to perform a LAG function to calculate the datediff between the first and last records. All records have the same alarm_id

I have created the LAG function, but cannot insert into it the formula which gets the max(RowID) to use in the statement:

```
SELECT [da_id]
       ,[db_addr]
      ,[time] as DTT
      ,[alarm_id]
      ,DATEDIFF(minute, LAG([time]) OVER(PARTITION BY [alarm_id] ORDER BY [time]),[time]) as TimeToClearInMins
      ,LAG([time]) OVER(PARTITION BY [alarm_id] ORDER BY [time]) as DTT2
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [alarm_id] ORDER BY [time]) as RowID  
  FROM [SQL-CCDM-EDM].[ReportingDataWarehouse].[iSCADA].[Events]
  where
  cast([time] as date) = ' 2023-06-13'
  and alarm_level in ('1','2','3','4') 
  and process <> 'NULL' 
  and (alarm_status <> old_alarm_status or wrkstn_number > 0)
  and server_id = 1 
  and alarm_id in (844820288, 840408001)
```

Result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxQfI.png)

I have tried grouping and using the having clause to pull out the max(RowID) but cannot get it to work. Could someone please tell me how to use the max(RowID) in the LAG function.

Comment: Do you need `LAG`? - can you just use `MIN([time]) OVER (PARTITION BY [alarm_id])`

Comment: Sample data and expected results as text not images would help immensely

Answer (score 0):

Would adding a cross apply solve your problem without a lag?

```
cross apply (select datediff(minute,MIN(time),MAX(time)) as Duration 
             from [SQL-CCDM-EDM].[ReportingDataWarehouse].[iSCADA].[Events] e2
             where e2.AlarmID=events.alarmID) ca
```

You can change your scale of time by changing the minute to something else.

In case you don't know where to put the cross apply, it goes directly after your from line.

This could also be added as a CTE to get them for all alarmIDs and then join that in.